# SQL sum field when column values match

Tags: sql, sum

The title was hard to word but the question is pretty simple. I searched all over here and could not find something for my specific issue so here it is. I'm usuing Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2010.

Table Currently looks like this

```
  | Value | Product Name|
  |  300  | Bike        |
  |  400  | Bike        |
  |  300  | Car         |
  |  300  | Car         |
```

I need the table to show me the sum of Values where Product Name matches - like this

```
  | TOTAL | ProductName |
  |  700  | Bike        |
  |  600  | Car         |
```

I've tried a simple

```
 SELECT
      SUM(Value) AS 'Total'
      ,ProductName
 FROM TableX
```

But the above doesn't work. I end up getting the sum of all values in the column. How can I sum based on the product name matching?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Value) AS 'Total', [Product Name]
FROM TableX  
GROUP BY [Product Name]
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3366/2)

Comment: I knew it should be something simple! This worked just fine. Thanks =)

Answer (score 4):

Anytime you use an aggregate function, (`SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX` ... ) with a column in the `SELECT` statement, you must use `GROUP BY`. This is a group function that indicates which column to group the aggregate by. Further, any columns that are not in the aggregate cannot be in your `SELECT` statement.

For example, the following syntax is invalid because you are specifying columns (`col2`) which are not in your `GROUP BY` (even though MySQL allows for this):

```
SELECT col1, col2, SUM(col3)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1
```

The solution to your question would be:

```
SELECT ProductName, SUM(Value) AS 'Total'
FROM TableX
GROUP BY ProductName
```

Comment: *Anytime you use an aggregate function, (SUM, MIN, MAX ... ) you must use GROUP BY.* - This is incorrect, you may wish to aggregate on the entire set, or on a portion restricted by a `WHERE` clause. See [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3366/3/0)

Comment: @RedFilter Should have explicitly stated this applies when using non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` list. I've updated my answer to reflect this.