# Firebase sum all child entries when child values match

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have saw this question in sql  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713187/sql-sum-field-when-column-values-match) but how this will be implement in firebase. This is my firebase structure 
[image: database]

I need to sum up the expenses total as per name . I need output like this

**output**

```
petrol:25
oil:83
gross:25
```

I have tried below code

```
expensesaddref=databaseReference.child(username).child(monthyr);
totaldatabaseref=databaseReference.child(username).child("Expense Cost").child(monthyr);
expensesaddref.orderByChild("expensesName").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d("Tag", "on  exp total");
        int tot=0;
        String exp = null;
        for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            ExpenseClass expenseAdd=ds.getValue(ExpenseClass.class);
            tot+=expenseAdd.getTotal();
            exp=expenseAdd.getExpensesName();

        }
        ExpenseClass expensesAdd=new ExpenseClass(exp,tot);
        String ref= "expensescost_"+ expensesAdd.getExpensesName();
        totaldatabaseref.child(ref).setValue(expensesAdd);
        Log.d("TAG", exp + "");
        Log.d("TAG", tot + "");


        Log.d("Tag", "After exp total");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I got the output as 0. Please help me

Comment: Hey @madhushri if my answer helped you, consider clicking the V type tick mark looking button next to it, it should turn green. I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `orderByChild()` and then get the `total` child value to sum it.
What I am saying looks something like this in code:

```java
ref.child("October_2018").orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo("oil").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                  int sum=0;
                  sum += data.child("total").getValue(Integer.class);  


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Here `ref` is `DatabaseReference` to your Firebase database.

Comment: I need sums of all the expenses name like petrol,oil,gross .if petrol have two values then it should sum it too

Comment: You can just replace the variable name in `equalTo()`. It will get the sum of all the Childs with the name of `oil` `petrol` or any other one.

Comment: If this answer helped you, consider marking it as correct and upvoting it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: if i entered october_2018 it should display all the expenses name under it.I dont need seperate expenses name

Comment: I am not sure I am getting you correctly. What I am saying is that `ref` is the reference to the original main child of your database which I can see in the picture, that is `October_2018`. Below them are names of different child nodes and you want to have sum of any of them, say `petrol` then you need to change the "oil" string with "petrol" in `equalTo()` and it will do the needful.

Comment: ya i can get you but i need all expenses under it at once when i click october_2018.`equalTo()` query will generate details about the name inside it but i dont need that. I need all the details all once when october_2018 button is clicked

Comment: This may be a different question you should try asking. But, for that, you have to remove the `orderByChild()`  and `equalTo()` statement. If the answer helped you, consider marking it as correct and upvoting it. I'd appreciate that.

Comment: ```int sum=0;``` must be put outside of the ```for``` loop. If not, the sum variable gets set to 0 each time the for loop passes through a child inside the children.