# Firebase sums all the child nodes when the name is equal

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i have followed [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687263/firebase-sum-all-child-entries-when-child-values-match) and i know this may be a duplicate qestion but my total is empty.I need to sum all the child nodes by `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()`.My Firebase Structure.I need the total sum of oil

[image]

**Expected Output**

```
oil 83
```

**UPDATE**

> Here user will select the month to view the cost and i will get it from other activity.In firebase structure `October_2018` is the `monthYr`

**MainActivity**

```
 listfirebaseref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Expenses Details").child(username).child("Expense_Month").child(monthYr);
 Log.d("TAG","before");
    listfirebaseref.orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo("oil").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("Tag", "on ");
                    Toast.makeText(MonthTotalexpenses.this,""+sum,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d("Tag", " " + sum);
                }

            }
            Log.d("Tag", " list ");
            }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I Know I am close to it but where iam missing.Please help

**My Log**

[image]

It doesn't print this `Log.d("Tag", " " + sum);`

**Firebase Rules**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true

    ,"Expenses Details": {
      ".write": "query.orderByChild != null && query.equalTo != null",
      "$uid": {
     ".indexOn": "expensesName"
  }
}

  }


}
```

> If i remove `orderByChild` and `equalTo` from `listfirebaseref.orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo("oil").addValueEventListener` it goes inside the For loop and if I add `orderByChild` and `equalTo` it again it doesn't go inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 listfirebaseref.orderByChild("expenseName").equalTo("oil")
```

to

```
listfirebaseref.orderByChild("expensesName").equalTo("oil")
```

Comment: Still its empty and its doesn't display the Toast also

Comment: please update your question with logs ( what is printed in log with TAG)? Please check spelling names for other nodes as well

Comment: See my update **MainActivity**.There is nothing in Log and it doesn't display this line also `Log.d("Tag", " " + sum);`

Comment: @PadmaPriya - can you print this Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange():" + dataSnapshot.toString()); before your for loop?

Comment: No its not printing,nothing is printing inside the OnDataChange loop

Comment: can you update your question with data from Expenses Details->UserName->MonthYear.. .. also what is value inside monthYr variable?