# how to add values from one column in reference to other column of having same value

Tags: sql

how to add values from one column in reference to other column of having same value
for eg:-

```
column1     | column2
   mat      |    80
   math     |    50
   math     |    60
   engl     |    70
   engl     |    40
   engl     |    50
   engl     |    90
   phy      |    70
   phy      |    60
   phy      |    40
   phy      |    80
```

Answer:-

```
column1     | column2
   mat      |    190
   engl     |     250
   phy      |     250
```

Comment: GROUP BY, SUM()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL sum field when column values match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713187/sql-sum-field-when-column-values-match)

Answer (score 1):

to add the different values of one column (column2) you use the SQL function 'SUM' which takes as argument the column containing the values, so Sum(column2)
now you want these Sums to be related to the key of another column (column1) so your request would look like this

```
select column1, SUM(column2) from Table
```

with this request you will obtain that output

```
 column1     | SUM(column2)
   math     |    190
   math     |    190
   math     |    190
   engl     |    250
   engl     |    250
   engl     |    250
   engl     |    250
   phy      |    250
   phy      |    250
   phy      |    250
   phy      |    250
```

as you can see the data was added as you wanted but you are getting unnecessary duplicates
you can remove these duplicates by adding GROUP BY at the end of your request + the key related to the sums you calculated (column1)

so your final request would be

```
select column1, SUM(column2) from Table GROUP BY column1
```

and output would be

```
    column1     | column2
   math      |    190
   engl     |     250
   phy      |     250
```