# How to merge two records and sum a column too in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a simple table with two columns. Col1 is like an identifier.

I want to SUM the quantity of rows with the same Col1 value. And **UPDATE** the current table.

Current table:

```
Col1 | Quantity
-----+----------
12   | 3
15   | 7
12   | 2
```

The **UPDATED** table I need is to SUM the quantity of two rows with Col1=12 (e.g .. WHERE Col1=12 ...) and Merge Them as one row:

```
Col1 | Quantity
-----+----------
12   | 5
15   | 7
```

How is it possible in a SQL Server query?

Please note that I need to update the table. Not just select rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL sum field when column values match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713187/sql-sum-field-when-column-values-match)

Comment: Question edited. I need to UPDATE my current table. Not just selecting a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MERGE statement for this.
Like with the UPDATE statement it's possible to combine with a Common-Table-Expression.
And in the CTE the window functions can be used.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by Col1 order by Quantity) as rn,
   SUM(Quantity) OVER (partition by Col1) as TotalQuantity,
   COUNT(*) OVER (partition by Col1) as Cnt
  FROM TestTable
)
MERGE (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE cnt > 1) target
USING (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE cnt > 1 AND rn = 1) src
ON (src.Col1 = target.Col1 AND src.rn = target.rn)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET target.Quantity = source.TotalQuantity;
```

A test on rexrester [here](https://rextester.com/BKC43213)

Such statement would however update all records of the table each time you re-run it.  Even when the dups were already deleted.
But with a few tweaks it'll become a MERGE query that doesn't update those that have no dups.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Col1, Quantity,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by Col1 order by Quantity DESC) as rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER (partition by Col1) as cnt,
        SUM(Quantity) OVER (partition by Col1) as TotalQuantity
        FROM TestTable
    ) q
    WHERE cnt > 1
)
MERGE CTE t
USING (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1) src
ON (src.Col1 = t.Col1 AND src.rn = t.rn)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET t.Quantity = src.TotalQuantity;
```

Answer (score 2):

use `sum()` aggregation with `group by`

```
with cte as 
(
select col1,quantity,row_number() over(partition by col1 order by quantity) as rn
from tablename
)

    update a set a.quantity=b.qty
    from cte a 
    inner join
    (select col1, sum(quantity) as qty
        from tablename
        group by col1
    )b on a.col1=b.col1 where rn=1

delete a from tablename a
join
(
select col1,quantity,row_number() over(partition by col1 order by quantity) as rn
    from tablename
)b on a.col1=b.col1 and rn>2
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to permanently update the data. And DELETE the second row.

Comment: @user1422847, I've updated my answer - you can check

Comment: Thanks a lot. It almost works. But I dont why there's error on last line (delete), an says Invalid object name 'cte'.

Comment: @user1422847, i've removed the semicolon after update , could u please check now

Comment: I've checked it but not helped